# babel doesn't have tree shaking?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

In my package.json, I have the following

```
"build": "babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps",
```

In one of my `js` files, I have

```js
import { MyFunc } from 'package-example`
```

Then I run `npm run build`. It builds, creates a dist folder.

Somehow, in my built file, I find this:

```
const package-example = require('package-example')
```

This somehow means that tree shaking doesn't work and the whole `package-example` gets included in the built.

Q1. Is this the correct assumption ?

Q2. How can I still have tree shaking so that only `MyFunc` gets imported ? I can't use webpack for now. is this not possible without webpack/rollup at all with only `babel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel processes files at an individual level. Tree-shaking requires project-wide awareness of what files are and aren't being used, so Babel does not, and cannot, do this. You would need Webpack or Rollup or some other build/bundling tool for this.